# How do I put an int in a string (java)

Tags: java, string

Here's my problem:

```
public class Sum {

  private int sum;
  private String sequence = " ";

  public int getSum() {
    return sum;
  }

  public void setSum(int sum) {
    this.sum = sum;
  }

  public String getSequence() {
    return sequence;
  }

  public void setSequence(int sum) {
    this.sequence = sequence + " " + sum;
  }

}
```

And the types are incompatible in line 15, which is "required: int"

Can anybody help me with this? Please and thank you.

***edit**
Sorry for not being able to put line 15. Line 15 is:

```
return sequence;
```

Comment: Make sure that *is* the code that is being compiled and *is* the code with the error. There is nothing in there that should result in a compile error.

Comment: What's the code at line 15? I don't see anything glaringly obvious.

Comment: I have edited the question and added line 15 for those who are asking. Using java.

Comment: As others have made obvious, the code as displayed here works. You are not compiling the code you think you are.

Comment: have you tried something like "clean project" in eclipse (or whatever you are using)?

Comment: There is nothing in your code that will cause a compiler error. [Demo](http://ideone.com/px01M)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you are asking for but you can convert int to String via `String sequence= Integer.toString(sum);` and String to int via `int sum = Integer.parseInt(sequence.trim());`

Answer (score 0):

The java code actually works pretty well for me, I'm compiling it with Java 1.6.0_24 on a Mac. Have you tried to implement a main to do some debug?

```
public static void main(String args[]){
                  Sum s = new Sum();
                  s.setSequence(3);
                  s.setSequence(9);
                  System.out.println(s.getSequence());
              }
```